# Creating an iterator that takes in a list and reverses it

Tags: python, list, iterator

I'm creating an iterator that takes in a list and reverses it. For some reason when I run my code, I keep getting "count" is not defined. Everything seems to be indented just fine or at least I thought. Some help would be very appreciative

Here's my code:

```
class RevIter():
    def __iter__(self):
        self.nums = ( [1, 2 ,3, 4, 5] )
        self. index = 0
        return self
    def __next__(self):
         if self.index <= 6:      
            count = self.nums[self.index]
            return count
         else:
            raise StopIteration
        
            
for i in RevIter():
    print(count.reverse())
```

Comment: Why is there a `count` outside the class in the loop?

Comment: Also, you never change, `index` in `__next__` so your iterator will just give you the same value each time.

Comment: Note, your iterator *doesn't accept any arguments*. You probably want to accept `nums` in `__init__`

Comment: And if you want to reverse the list, you need to start index from `len() - 1` and go down by 1 till 0

Comment: Anyway, the error is pretty straight-forward... *there is no `count` defined*... why do you think there should be? What do you think `count` is referring to?

Answer (score 2):

To make a proper iterable class

- move the initialization in the `__init__`
- change `self.index` in the `__next__` method, if you don't move it you'll get an infinite iterable that yield the always same value
- just use `i` in the main code

```py
class RevIter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        self.index = len(self.nums) - 1

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if 0 <= self.index < len(self.nums):
            count = self.nums[self.index]
            self.index -= 1
            return count
        else:
            raise StopIteration

for i in RevIter():
    print(i)

5
4
3
2
1
```

---

For a forward iteration

```py
class RevIter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        self.index = 0

    def __next__(self):
        if 0 <= self.index < len(self.nums):
            count = self.nums[self.index]
            self.index += 1
            return count
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```

Answer (score 1):

In your for loop you are printing `(count.reverse())`. Here you are telling python there is an object called `count`, but there is no such object.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print the count variable which is not instant imaged in your for loop !